# Recursive search in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have employee table, where employee id and supervisor is present. I want to find the hierarchy for the employee in five levels.

Example: Employee 1 is reported to 2, 2 reported to 4,4 reported to 17, 17 reported to 20. But we not able to find 20 supervisor so we kept the supervisor for 20 is 20 itself.

| EmployeeID | SupervisiorID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 8 | 6 |
| 9 | 5 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 4 | 17 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 10 | 20 |
| 15 | 20 |
| 17 | 20 |
| 16 | 21 |
| 15 | 13 |
| 14 | 12 |
| 13 | 11 |

Excepted output

| EmployeeID | SupervisiorID_1 | SupervisiorID_2 | SupervisiorID_3 | SupervisiorID_4 | SupervisiorID_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 17 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 4 | 17 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 8 | 6 | 3 | 15 | 20 | 20 |
| 9 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 6 | 3 | 15 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 5 | 10 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 4 | 17 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 3 | 15 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 10 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 15 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 17 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 16 | 21 | 21 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 15 | 13 | 11 | 11 | 11 | 11 |
| 14 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 12 |
| 13 | 11 | 11 | 11 | 11 | 11 |

How can we achieve this in Spark using dataframe recursively.

Comment: https://github.com/pcbzmani/hierarchy_spark
Please review this solution and suggest some enhancements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this has been asked many times, someone here https://dwgeek.com/spark-sql-recursive-dataframe-pyspark-and-scala.html/ has solved this.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 5 levels, than it is better to use 4 joins to do the job.
In my point of view, spark doesn't support natively recursive solutions for such scenario. If you really want to do it in a recursive way, you may need to collect the data u need and do it on driver locally.